# Summing $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^{\alpha+1}} {}_2F_1(1, 1+\alpha, 2+\alpha,\frac{1}{1+k} ) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, hypergeometric-function

I know the series converges but I can't find a closed expression. 
The parameter $\alpha > 1$ and $_2 F_1$ is the hypergeometric function.

Thanks!